# Creating own singly linked list to sort

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create my own singly linked list in java and then use it to perform sorting.
I only have access to **first** node and **next** is a pointer used to point to next node.
Every node contains 2 fields x and y which are both integers.
How do I add elements to a linked list without using the built in methods and the sort them using either quicksort or merge sort?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried until now

Comment: So... you're trying to insert a node into a list without using any of the class methods? This is either extremely bad code style or simply not achievable.

Comment: @Paul, 'built-in methods' is probably not the same as class methods.  I think the assignment was probably to do it yourself, and not use any built-in Java constructs.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add elements to a linked list without using the built in methods and the sort them using either quicksort or merge sort?

Fast algorithms like quicksort and mergesort depend on being able to >>index<< the array of elements being sorted; i.e. in operation sequences like `a[i] = a[j]`.  Using a linked list means that random indexing will be an `O(N)` operation.  This is likely to turn an `O(N log N)` algorithm into an `O(N^2 log N)` one.

If you look at Java's built-in sort methods (in various versions of Java), you will see that sorting a `LinkedList` is done by:

- copying the list to a temporary array,
- sorting the array, and
- clearing and copying the array back to the list.

This is the most efficient approach for sorting a large linked list.

Comment: The point about mergesort and quicksort being applied to a linked list is only partially right. In a doubly linked list, both merge and quicksort could be implemented in an efficient manner - for quicksort this would be dependent upon how the pivot is chosen, but it's not impossible to achieve the normal run time of `O(n log n)`, resp. `O(n ^ 2)` worst case.

Comment: Maybe, if you were really clever about it.  However, implementing fast sorting for large linked lists is still a crazy thing to attempt.  He should either be using an array-based list, or sorting using bubblesort ... which would be relatively easy to implement for a single-linked list